# Problem getting ar_mailer/ar_sendmail working on new server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail, sendgrid, ar-mailer

Hey all.  I've got a new app up and running on a new ubuntu server.  It's working fine generally but i can't get ar_sendmail working.  I'm following the instructions on this page:
http://www.ameravant.com/posts/sending-tons-of-emails-in-ruby-on-rails-with-ar_mailer

The setup is all done, ie i can "deliver mails" which just saves records in my Email table. Now i want to get the ar_sendmail daemon running to actually send them.  (so i'm at 'Running ar_sendmail in daemon mode' in that web page).

First thing:

```
ar_sendmail --mailq
>>ar_sendmail: command not found
```

Ok...so, where is ar_sendmail?  I have a look and there's an ar_sendmail file in the bin folder of the ar_mailer plugin, so i add the location of that to my path.  I don't know if this was the right thing to do or not.

Ok, so try again.

```
ar_sendmail --mailq
/var/www/apps/millionaire/vendor/plugins/ar_mailer/bin/ar_sendmail:3:in `require': no such file to load -- action_mailer/ar_sendmail (LoadError)
    from /var/www/apps/millionaire/vendor/plugins/ar_mailer/bin/ar_sendmail:3
```

hmm.  Here's the offending file, there's not much there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'action_mailer/ar_sendmail'

ActionMailer::ARSendmail.run
```

ok...so it literally is just trying to require this and can't find it.  The file, action_mailer/ar_sendmail.rb is in the ar_mailer plugin, in it's lib folder.  So, given that it's being called from inside the plugin, it should be able to see this right?

I've got a feeling that i'm way off the track here and have missed something simple.  Can anyone set me straight?  I'm using rails 2.3.4 in case that's relevant.

EDIT - i just realised something kind of dumb:  when i call ar_sendmail from the command line like this, i'm just loading that one file, which doesn't know where it's supposed to look for the rest of the stuff, i think.  Which really makes me think that i'm not trying to run the right thing.  Is the ar_sendmail daemon a seperate program altogether, that i would get with apt_get or something?

EDIT2 - i made some progress by installing the ar_mailer gem (which the guide said i shouldn't do) and that does seem to run.  It's sending some mail request *somewhere* and clearing the Email table of pending emails.  Running ar_sendmail in -ov (oneshot verbal) mode i see it report this for example:

sent email 00000000019 from from@address.com to to@address.com: #

So, it actually looks like it's working now and i just need to set up the ACTUAL THING WHICH SENDS EMAILS.  sigh.  still grateful for any advice.

thanks, max

Comment: How did you get both `ar_mailer` and sendgrid working. `ar_mailer` requires me to set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` to `:activerecord` and to use sendgrid, I need to set it to `:smtp`. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an smtp server. Checkout [www.sendgrid.com](http://www.sendgrid.com).